# Can't reload ActiveRecord association from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, reload

Spent a working day on this.

I have

```
class Box
  has_many :users, :through => :subscriptions
end
```

I also have custom `insert_new_users` and `associate_with(new_users)` methods which use multiple INSERT to do their job quickly. Anyway, they work fine. I also have this line at the end of "associate_with" method:

```
def associate_with
  # mysql INSERT here
  self.users(true) # Should force reload
end
```

It works as expected when running in test environment (both controller and model tests) and it fails as expected if I remove the `true` argument, which forces the reload. It also works from `script/console` in development if I `update_attributes` the model. But fails in development or production when I'm trying to `update_attributes` from controller. It simply does not reload associations and I can see it in logs, where it says "CACHE (0.0ms)" for this query.

The weird thing - it worked before and I can't identify the moment it stopped working due to some reasons. I was hoping maybe someone knows how is this possible.

Answer (score 3):

You're seeing the effects of the ActiveRecord SQL query cache.

Either wrap the pre-INSERT references to the `users` association in a call to `uncached`

```
self.class.uncached do
  # ...
end
```

This will stop ActiveRecord from caching the results of any queries inside the block. If you have code in many places, this may be annoying.

You can also clear the cache after you are done with your inserts by calling `connection.clear_query_cache`.

Comment: Unfortunately it says undefined method `uncached' when calling from inside the model.

Comment: Good catch. It's a class method, not an instance. I fixed the scope in my answer.

Comment: Is this a bug in Rails then? It seems to me that calling reload should really reload. Though it's possible the SQL query cache is smart enough to know that the database hasn't actually changed. In which case, this isn't really something to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

So far I've been able to trick AR with the following:

```
def associate_with
  # mysql INSERT here
  @users = self.users.find(:all, :conditions => ['users.id IS NOT NULL'])
end

def users
  @users || self.users
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've been able to fully clear the cache is to call `reload`.  For example, you could call

`User.reload`

and it should force a cache clear including of any relations or associations.