# Ruby on Rails: Why first active record query takes longer?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

If i execute active record query after some time gap, it takes longer.

Say Item.all takes .11 sec on first query and .003 later on. what could be possible reason for this behaviour?

edited:
active record query cache 's scope is action of controller. In my case, active record query in subsequent http request is also faster.

Answer (score 4):

Possible explanations:

1. ActiveRecord Caching
2. Connection Pooling (it doesn't have to restart the connection)
3. Load on the web server or db server.

Comment: "Connection Pooling (it doesn't have to restart the connection)", please elaborate

Comment: Typically when connecting to a database a TCP connection is established, once the connection is established it is placed in a pool to be re-used.  The overhead of establishing the connection to the database is then reduced for future connections, improving resource use and response time.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord caches the results from queries.  The first query is actually hitting the database - ActiveRecord then waits for the operation to complete and parses the results into its objects.  The next time an identical query is made, it has the results cached so that they are returned to you immediately, instead of going all the way back to the database.

Check the [API for the QueryCache](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/QueryCache.html#method-i-clear_query_cache): it seems like you can clear the query cache (`connection.clear_query_cache`) if you want to wipe out cached queries.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966012/cant-reload-activerecord-association-from-controller) also suggests `self.class.uncached do ... end` to bypass the cache but I am not sure if this still applies in Rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely ActiveRecord's caching you're looking at. [See doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).

> All of the methods are built on a simple caching principle that will
>   keep the result of the last query around unless specifically
>   instructed not to. The cache is even shared across methods to make it
>   even cheaper to use the macro-added methods without worrying too much
>   about performance at the first go.