# Rails - uncached controller action messing with serialized attribute

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, caching

I have a controller action that calls a model method which generates a serialized list of data pulled from another model database. I need this to be `uncached` because the SQL queries should be random data pulls.

Here's a general idea of my code (Note that `User` `has_one` `Foo`, `Bar` is an arbitrary model of data, `:data_list` is of type `text`, and the database is SQLite):

`# app/models/foo.rb`

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :data_list

  def generate_data
    list = []
    for i in 1..4
      data = Bar.find(:first, :order => "Random()")
      list << data
    end
    self.data_list = list
  end
end
```

`# app/controllers/users_controller.rb`

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def generate_action
    ...
    uncached do
      @user.foo.generate_data
    end
    @user.foo.save
  end
end
```

`# app/views/user/show.html.erb`

```
...
<% @user.foo.data_list.each do |data| %>
  <%= data %><br />
<% end %>
```

Whenever `uncached do ... end` is removed, everything works fine and the `show` view prints out each set of `Bar` objects in  `@user.foo.data_list`. Unfortunately, because of Rails' SQL caching, it ends up look like this:

> RandomDataPoint8
>   RandomDataPoint8
>   RandomDataPoint8
>   RandomDataPoint8

When I need to look like this:

> RandomDataPoint7
>   RandomDataPoint13
>   RandomDataPoint2
>   RandomDataPoint21

It should be noted that running `user.foo.generate_data` from Rails command line works perfectly with the randomization. It is only when being called from the controller that caching starts to occur.

My research suggested I use `uncached` in the controller to remove caching, however it seems to destroy my data serialization and I receive the error:

`undefined method 'each' for #<String:0x007ff49008dc70>`

In fact, it does this even if I retroactively add in `uncached` (having successfully generated a `data_plan` without `uncached` prior) and save the controller, but don't call `generate_action`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**
I believe this problem is actually related to the fact that I was storing an object in the hash. Switching to the object `id` fixed this problem. Another SO question of mine regarding this can be found here:
[Rails - Accessing serialized data from console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711696/rails-accessing-serialized-data-from-console)

The following has been preserved just because the syntax may still help people, but I don't believe it was the actual cause of the problem.

---

I solved this by moving `uncached` to the model. For reference, the source I was using to originally solve this problem was this link: http://railspikes.com/2008/8/18/disabling-activerecord-query-caching-when-needed

What I overlooked is that he puts `uncached` in the model, not the controller. Also, the syntax needed to be a little different:

```
# app/models/foo.rb

self.class.uncached do
   ...
end
```

instead of

```
uncached do
  ...
end
```

The source for the syntax correction is this SO response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/967690/337903