# Rails - Accessing serialized data from console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, console

For some reason, whenever I access a serialized attribute from the console, it treats it as a normal string. The serialization/deserialization works fine when not accessed from the console (ex. from the view). I have the code as follows:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  serialize :serialized_data    # column type is text
  ...
end
```

For example, if I were to put in `app/views/users/show.html.erb` the following:

```
<%= @user.foo.serialized_data.first %>
```

It would properly print out the first of the set of data. When I run the following command from console:

```
> User.first.foo.serialized_data.first
```

It would simply print out `-`, which is the first character of a YAML file. Further, `User.first.foo.serialized_data` would print out a large string rather than the array/hash that was originally saved.

UPDATE:
If I generate the data in `:serialized_data` and attempt to access it in the same console session, it seems to work fine. Once I close console and then re-enter it, the issue occurs.

EDIT:
For clarification, `:serialized_data` is an array of hashes in the following form:

```
[{"stuff" => {"name" => name, "qty" => 1}}, {"stuff" => {"name" => name2, "qty" => 3}}]
```

and can be accessed as such:

```
user.foo.serialized_data[0]["stuff"]["qty"]
=> 1
```

EDIT 2:
It may also be important to note that I am storing a model object in my hash. As mentioned in the comments below, if we were to use the example I gave, `user.foo.serialized_data[0]["stuff"]["name"]` would return an object of model `Name` with attributes. So, I could run `user.foo.serialize_data[0]["stuff"]["name"].id` and so on. Maybe the object is messing with the syntax of the YAML file.

Comment: What's the data that you are serializing? One app i had worked on involved serializing a hash. This hash then came back as a hash as expected, where i could do something like `@combat_instance.entities.first[1].attack_damage`, where entities was the serialized data. I'm using 1, as the zero index of each array in the hash is an id. So if you want to serialize something else than just a hash, adjust the method that sets the serialized_data value.

Comment: what happens if you run access `:serialized_data` in the console a second time?

Comment: @agmcleod - In the hash, I'm serializing an object. Using my question's example, `user.foo.serialized_data[0]["stuff"]["name"]` would actually return an object of model `Name`. I've updated my question.

Comment: @MichaelSlade - The second time around, it simply returns a string of the YAML file. Accessing the first object of what should be an array merely returns the first character of the YAML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was storing an entire object in the hash value, as mentioned in EDIT 2. Switching it to the object `id` fixed this issue.